# How to create cookies for login name and password in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to store login name and password in cookies when click on a "remember me" checkbox. My `login.cshtml` looks like `input type="text"` , `id="loginName"` and `input type="password" id = "password"`. How can I do this?

Comment: #1 Never store passwords as cookies!

Comment: @Jaimin Please don't use backticks for non-code - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why. And you could have improved so much more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   // create a cookie
        HttpCookie loginName = new HttpCookie("loginName", model.LoginName);
        loginName.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
        Response.Cookies.Add(loginName);

       HttpCookie password= new HttpCookie("password", model.Password);
        password.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
        Response.Cookies.Add(password);
```

Comment: I'd love to downvote this for showing how to do a bad thing, i.e. storing a password in a cookie instead of using an authentication cookie, but unfortunately this _is_ what OP asked for...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: you are right, password saving is not good approach. But O/P is asking.

Comment: True :/ Though it never hurts resolving an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) by showing what OP _should_ use ;)

Comment: thanks @AmitAgrawal for this solution but i want to implement this functionality on rememberMe checkbox if checkbox is true.

Comment: On Post request check if remember me is checked then executed this.